# Why does nginx + memcache corrupt my response body?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, nginx

I'm caching some web pages in memcache. When I read the page directly from the cache, the page is well formed like this ...

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"-:--     0
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

but when I use a browser or curl to read it from nginx (version 0.8.50), it looks like response headers are ending up in the body of the response like this ...

```
     �{
        "    ETag"'"16bb9f51667d334aa4e7663ca28d308a""X-Runtime177"Content-Type"text/html; charset=utf-8"Content-Length"5428"Set-Cookie""Cache-Control"(private, max-age=0, must-revalidate"4<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

My nginx config is pretty simple ...

```
     set $memcached_key $cookie__app_session$uri;
     memcached_pass     localhost:11211;
     default_type       text/html;
         error_page         404 502 /fallback$uri;
```

Does anyone have an idea why the response is corrupt?

Comment: What curl parameters are you using? You may be asking to see the http headers in addition to the http body (the page). And when you say "read the page directly from the cache" what do you mean? Using a browser or curl?

Comment: @Larry Thanks, there was a problem with the question - I should have made it clear that the problem happens when using a browser or curl. Reading from memcache is via a client. The contents of memcache are definitely correct.

Answer (score 2):

#### Do! Stupid developer problem!

There were two mistakes

(a) I was storing the response header and body in memcache, then adding headers in an nginx rule. Storing only the response body in memcache removed the bulk of the problems

(b) I was storing the response in Ruby's marshal format (the default setting in memcache-client) - reading the contents of memcache using a simple Ruby client was hiding the fact that the format was not directly usable by nginx.

Hope that helps someone sometime!

Chris